# How to update Visual Studio 2017 using command line?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'd like to automatically update my Visual Studio 2017 installation from a script (running this script at session login).

`vs_installer` shows a bunch of command line arguments (using `/?`). So I tried :

`& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" update --passive --norestart`

However, nothing happens. I see the process in the task manager for a few seconds, but the product is not updated.

How to update my VS installation ?
Is is possible to handle the installer update ?

PS: if possible, I'd to have a passive update, not an invisible update. I'd prefer seeing the product being updated to avoid launching a new instance while the update is in progress.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found partially the answer. I have to specify the install path of visual studio to let the installer knows what to update:

`& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" update --passive --norestart --installpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise"` (assuming default path).

I still have to look for updates of the installer itself, but since I've the latest version, I've to wait for a new release.

**[Edit 04/10/2019]** The update process is similar with VS **2019** (at least from 16.0 to 16.0.1). I can update both version using :

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" -ArgumentList "update --passive --norestart --installpath ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise"""
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" -ArgumentList "update --passive --norestart --installpath ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise"""
```

I use `Start-Process` with `-Wait` to avoid returning control before the end of the update.

Comment: Confirmed that this works with VS 2017 Update 4. The command auto runs the installer UI and updates. Thanks!

Comment: Also confirmed that this updates the installer first, if required.

Comment: vs_installer.exe have also a --wait parameter so you can get rid of the Start-Process cmdlet.